# Set up ignore block comments for Simian Ant Task

Tags: java, ant, simian

Is it possible to set up start and end comments for disabling simian in an Ant task?  I've seen various forums talking about a command line option to disable simian for certain blocks of code using comments and I have tried this in the Ant task doing something like this:

```
<simian ignoreBlocks="simian-start:simian-stop" .... />
```

And then in the Java code, I have done the following

```
//simian-start
....
//simian-stop
```

However, the duplication is still detected between the bit of code between the comments above and the other class that has the same bit of code.

I also tried it the other way around just in case I have the ordering of the ignoreBlocks mixed up:

```
//simian-stop
....
//simian-start
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got it working just like you described. I am using simian 2.2.24. The command line call

```
java -jar ~/tmp/simian-2.2.24/simian-2.2.24.jar -ignoreBlocks="simian-off:simian-on" test.java
```

does not find code like this:

```
//simian-off
foo.bar();
//simian-on
```

Setting the ignoreBlocks attribute in the ant task the same way

```
<simian language="java" ignoreBlocks="simian-off:simian-on">
...
</simian>
```

also does not find the code.

Hth

Comment: At first I didn't notice why yours would have worked yet mine didn't.  Then I paid closer attention and noticed that the OFF has to come before the ON.  My silly mistake.  Thanks!

Comment: Just an extra note. I started a new project and got the same issue again. It turns out when I put // simian:off <some code> // simian:on it still didn't ignore that block but I had to actually remove the space between the // and the simian part(!!) - just an extra hint just in case someone runs into the problem.